# Layering mesh behind panorama

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to know if we can have an equirectangular panorama on the foreground and a mesh in the background so when users move across the panorama, the mouse would be able to pickup the plane information from behind.

I have tried loading a panorama using the below code but I couldn't find any way to  layer a mesh in the background.

```
var sphereBufferGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(500,60,40);
sphereBufferGeometry.scale( -1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( [panorama image])});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereBufferGeometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );
```

I have also tried loading the mesh(.obj) using the below code but the variable 'object' is of type THREE.Group and the variable 'child' returns multiple objects of type THREE.MESH. So, I am not sure how we can layer a panorama in the foreground.

```
objLoader.load( [objfile], function ( object ) {
  object.traverse( function ( child ) {
  });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the image on the page and add an image map to it. Do whatever you want with any cell that fires an event. For proof-of-concept, I simply logged the coordinates - top-left-corner ordered pair and bottom-right-corner ordered pair - for cells firing click events.

You could replace click with mouseover/-out calls. If you reduce the cell heights and width to 1px, you could track exact position as the mouse crosses the image...WARNING - lots of event-handling there.

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"">
      // convenience reference
      function get(eId) {return document.getElementById(eId);};

      // add area elements to an existing image map
      function paintMapGrid(imageId, gridId, cellHeight, cellWidth) {
          var imgHeight = get(imageId).height;
          var imgWidth = get(imageId).width;
          var lastJ = Math.floor(imgWidth/cellWidth);
          var lastI = Math.floor(imgHeight/cellHeight);
          var grid = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < lastI; i++) {
             for (var j = 0; j < lastJ; j++) {
                var coords= (cellWidth*j) + ',' + (cellHeight*i) + ',' +(cellWidth*(j+1) + ',' + (cellHeight*(i + 1))); 
                  grid += '<area onclick="logCellCoords(this);" shape="rect" coords="' + coords + '">';
             }
          }
          get('mesh').innerHTML = grid;
      };

      function logCellCoords(cRef) {
          console.log(cRef.coords);
      };

      window.onload = function() {
         // paint an image map on the image with id='meshImage', adding the 
         // area elements to the map with id="mesh"; cells are 16px wide 
         // and 16px tall
         paintMapGrid('meshImage', 'mesh', 16, 16);
      };
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <img src="yourPanoramicImage.jpg" alt="some 1024x668 panorama" 
         width="1024" height="668" usemap="#grid" id="meshImage"
      /> 
      <map name="grid" id="mesh"></map>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Afterthoughts...prob'ly less resource intensive to create each area element individually in the inner for loop and append it to its map parent rather than creating the entire HTML string for all and adding it all at once. Also, not sure how tolerant browsers would be for 1px areas, e.g., 1024x668 would need 684,032 area tags. My POC required 64x41 = 2624 area tags.

Comment: thanks for your time.. but it isn't clear how this would work with .obj meshes

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution. The idea is to have both spheregeometry and mesh in the same scene and make any initial position/rotation/scale changes to the mesh so that it aligns with the panorama. Once this is the done, any changes to the camera would affect both the objects in exactly same way giving the user an impression that these two objects are always aligned.